# How can I edit the message of a merged commit in Git?

Tags: git

Browsing the history of my Git repository, I found a wrong commit message.
How can I change the commit message.

The branch containing the commit has been merged to another branch.
Here is the history of a simplified model repository:

```
*  (HEAD, A) Merge branch 'B' into A
|\  
| * (B) 3rd
| * 2nd [wrong]
|/  
* (master) 1st
```

I tried `rebase`, but it didn't work as expected:

```
$ git checkout B
$ git rebase -i HEAD~2

edit 2nd [wrong]
pick 3rd

$ git commit –-amend

2nd [correct]

$ git rebase --continue
```

The result was:

```
* (HEAD, B) 3rd
* 2nd [correct]
| *   (A) Merge branch 'B' into A
| |\  
|/ /  
| * 3rd
| * 2nd [wrong]
|/  
* (master) 1st
```

The desired result is:

```
*  (HEAD, A) Merge branch 'B' into A
|\  
| * (B) 3rd
| * 2nd [correct]
|/  
* (master) 1st
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git filter-branch` if you really need it. Remember you'll get a *different* commit graph upper `2nd` commit, and all your users will have to refetch it.

The command you need looks like this (replace <BAD COMMIT ID> with actual sha1 of the bad commit):

```
git filter-branch --msg-filter '
    if test "$GIT_COMMIT" = <BAD_COMMIT_ID>; then cat <<EOF
This is a fixed commit message summary

This is a body
EOF
else cat; fi'
```

Carefully inspect results with `gitk --all`. The previous git commit graph is saved under `original/` prefix and can be restored if you need it.

Here what I got on a simple example:

```
alex@rhyme ~/tmp/git_repo $ git log --graph --oneline --all                               
*   3397c0e Merge 'B' into 'A'
|\  
| * 706c199 The third commit
| * c777ae4 The second commit
|/  
* 69e2e53 Initial commit
```

`master` is at 69e2e53, `B` at 706c199, `A` at 3397c0e.

After the command

```
alex@rhyme ~/tmp/git_repo $ git filter-branch --msg-filter '                              
    if test "$GIT_COMMIT" = c777ae4b35f07f5cebcde93d4c716bfca9fdea94; then cat <<EOF
This is a fixed commit message summary

This is a body
EOF
else cat; fi' A B
Rewrite 3397c0e62f155d6273186a2120667517e60519dd (4/4)
Ref 'refs/heads/A' was rewritten
Ref 'refs/heads/B' was rewritten
alex@rhyme ~/tmp/git_repo $ _
```

I got the following picture:

```
*   5e1db15 Merge 'B' into 'A'
|\  
| * d238654 The third commit
| * 2f0fb9f This is a fixed commit message summary
|/  
| *   3397c0e Merge 'B' into 'A'
| |\  
|/ /  
| * 706c199 The third commit
| * c777ae4 The second commit
|/  
* 69e2e53 Initial commit
```

with the following branches layout:

1. `master` left intact
2. `A` rewritten to 5e1db15
3. `B` rewritten to d238654
4. 3397c0e (former `A`) saved as `original/refs/heads/A`
5. 706c199 (former `B`) saved as `original/refs/heads/B`

Notice that commits to which point A and B will change in *any case* because their parent commit is changed. That's why you get a duplicate of your original commit graph. When you make sure that branches are modified correctly you may remove `original/*` branches

Comment: Thanks. I tried your command, but the results looked like `rebase` except timestamps. I used `git log --graph --oneline --all` instead of `gitk --all` because `gitk` was not installed.

Comment: This worked fine. How can I remove `original/*` branches? `git branch -d` didn't work.

Comment: :-) When you decide that you absolutely don't need them, simply remove .git/refs/original/*. Actually git branches are files inside .git/refs/heads/... or records in .git/packed-refs file pointing to a particular SHA1. So `git branch -D` is simply a sofisticated shortcut to `rm -f .... || sed -e '/...../d' .git/packed-refs :)